# python requests and bs4 how to navigate through the children of an element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

so this is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

URL = 'http://www.vn-meido.com/k1/index.php?board=17.0'

# loads page
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# gets the newest book
book = soup.select_one('td[class^="subject windowbg2"]').text

while True:
    # reloads the page
    r = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    # gets the newest book
    new_book = soup.select_one('td[class^="subject windowbg2"]').text
    # checks if a new book has been uploaded
    if book == new_book:
        print("no new book found")
    elif book != new_book:
        print(new_book)
        book = soup.select_one('td[class^="subject windowbg2"]').text
    # repeats after 30 seconds
    time.sleep(30)
```

but if you go to the website and have a look I get the text of the newest book uploaded but I want to be able to separate the title and the author and the title and author are in different elements but they don't have a way to identify them (like a class or an ID) so if you can help please do, thanks

Comment: you have to visit the specific thread to get the author, assuming you want the book author not thread author. Or is it the thread author you want?

Comment: yeah book author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming html remains consistent across entries (I only checked a few) then when next text is found under the pinned listings at the top (I assume this to be a new book) then you need to extract the book url, visit that url, then you can use ``:-soup-contains`to target author and book title by specific text and`next_sibling` to get the required return values.

N.B. I have removed the while loop for the purposes of this answer. The additions to the `elif` are the important ones.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


URL = 'http://www.vn-meido.com/k1/index.php?board=17.0'

# loads page
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# gets the newest book
book = ''   # for testing altered this line

r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
# gets the newest book
new_book = soup.select_one('td[class^="subject windowbg2"]').text
# checks if a new book has been uploaded
if book == new_book:
    print("no new book found")
elif book != new_book:
    print(new_book)
    new_book_url = soup.select_one('tr:not([class]) td:not([class*=stickybg]) ~ .subject a')['href']
    r = requests.get(new_book_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for member in ['TITLE ', 'AUTHOR']:
        print(soup.select_one(f'strong:-soup-contains("{member}")').next_sibling.next_sibling)
```